# EventMouseout in Fullcalendar with Qtip2

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, qtip2

i want use qtip2 in my fullcalendar but i have a problem with the eventMouseout().

When i switch between events near, the qtip is not displayed correctly.

The code that i use is this http://jsfiddle.net/Lknej/1/

```
eventMouseover: function(data, event, view) {
            var content = '<h3>'+data.title+'</h3>' + 
                '<p><b>Start:</b> '+data.start+'<br />' + 
                (data.end && '<p><b>End:</b> '+data.end+'</p>' || '');

            tooltip.set({
                'content.text': content
            })
            .reposition(event).show(event);
},
eventMouseout: function(data, event, view) {tooltip.hide()}
```

Comment: can you provide us your code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is another approach for getting tooltip on events

it can be done  without qtip2 plugin,
here is my code http://jsfiddle.net/539jx/3/

```
  eventMouseover: function (data, event, view) {

        tooltip = '<div class="tooltiptopicevent" style="width:auto;height:auto;background:#feb811;position:absolute;z-index:10001;padding:10px 10px 10px 10px ;  line-height: 200%;">' + 'title: ' + ': ' + data.title + '</br>' + 'start: ' + ': ' + data.start + '</div>';


        $("body").append(tooltip);
        $(this).mouseover(function (e) {
            $(this).css('z-index', 10000);
            $('.tooltiptopicevent').fadeIn('500');
            $('.tooltiptopicevent').fadeTo('10', 1.9);
        }).mousemove(function (e) {
            $('.tooltiptopicevent').css('top', e.pageY + 10);
            $('.tooltiptopicevent').css('left', e.pageX + 20);
        });


    },
    eventMouseout: function (data, event, view) {
        $(this).css('z-index', 8);

        $('.tooltiptopicevent').remove();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

my approach to resolve to that problem was as following

```
eventMouseover: function (data, event, view) {
        $('#ui-tooltip-0').css("display", "block");
        var content = 'Fetcha: <b>' + data.departureDate.split(' ')[0] + '</b> ' + 'Desde: <b>' + data.title + '</b>' +
              '<p><b>#viaje: ' + data.id + '</b><br /><b>' + $('#ddlEndTerminal option:selected').text().split(',')[0] + ': ' + data.arrivalDate.split(' ')[1]
            + '</b><br /><b>' + $('#ddlStartTerminal option:selected').text().split(',')[0] + ': ' + data.departureDate.split(' ')[1];

        tooltip.set({
            'content.text': content
        })
        .reposition(event).show(event);


    },
    eventMouseout: function (data, event, view) {   



        $('#ui-tooltip-0').css("display","none");

    },
```